# Adding 2 constraints to phone number column

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, psql

I need to add a constraint to an existing table so that the phone numbers can only be 10 digit mobile number or 8 digit landline number (with no spaces or area code).

This is the code I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE people

ADD CONSTRAINT digit_phoneno_8_10

CHECK (phoneno ~ '^[0-9]{8,10}$');
```

This is allowing for 9-digit phone numbers and I want to exclude that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly `n` digits or exactly `m` digits, you need to use the alternation `|` operator:

```
ALTER TABLE people

ADD CONSTRAINT digit_phoneno_8_10

CHECK (phoneno ~ '^(\d{8}|\d{10})$');
```